Separating audio m4b file based on a cue file
Separating audio m4b file based on a cue file
How can I split an audio m4b into separate files using a cue file?
Note: The m4b file has no chapters that's why I need to use the cue file to split it.
I did try AI but that didn't work.
ffmpeg -i test.m4b -f segment -segment_times test.cue -c copy output_%02d.m4a

I get errors.

Invalid time duration specification 'test.cue' in times list test.cue
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters
?): Invalid argument

The thing is I can load the cue file in vlc and play the different chapters without issues.
PS: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

This may not answer the question if you REALLY need ffmpeg, but it does discuss this problem regarding a variety of tools, including ffmpeg: https://superuser.com/questions/577476/split-audio-file-with-cue-file

@music2myear I really don't need to use ffmpeg but that seems like the most common / versatile thing used for users that use Linux.  I'm willing to try some other process if it works on Linux / Ubuntu.

One of the suggested solutions there is a python script using ffmpeg. I'd guess that may work on Ubuntu. The other answers appear to be more Windows-centric.
